# Is there a maximum width for Firefox/Chrome Extensions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am developing a chrome/firefox extension.

The extension seems to work fine in certain contexts (it fully displays all content):

[image: working_extension_situation]

However, it fails to work in other situations. Take a look at this example:

Before clicking on the extension:

[image: Before_Clicking_On_Extension]

And, after clicking on the extension:

[image]

In the second example it seems like the width of the extension is forcibly restricted to the width of the menu that contains the Library, Sidebars, and Summarizer buttons, even though I forcibly increased the extension's width with the following CSS:

```
body {
min-width: 500px;
}
```

Is it possible to circumvent this width restriction in the second example? Or, at the very least, is it possible to detect if the popup's width is being forcibly restricted?

If it is not possible to circumvent the width restriction, I would like to have the following behavior. When there is a restriction on the width of the extension popup, I would like to set the width of the popup to the maximum allowed width, but if there is no restriction on width, I would like to set the width of the popup to 500px. Can that be done?

Comment: You should take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Popups)

Comment: Most of what I can find just talks about the maximum width of Firefox/Chrome extensions in general - but that is different from my problem, which is that in a specific situation, the browser seems to enforce a different maximum limit for the width of the popup.

Comment: Take a look at the **Popup resizing** section on the page that I've mentioned.

Comment: Oh, I see. Hmm... do you know if there is anyway to detect if the width is fixed (i.e - the extension's button was clicked in the toolbar overflow)?

Comment: Yes, you can use JavaScript to determine the *view port*'s size and change your layout accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems for both the max size is 800x600 pixels.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Popups